# Istanbul with Node.js v6 destructured default parameter values

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, mocha.js, istanbul

**EDIT** Updated example since I copied the wrong one

**EDIT 2** Apparently, it is a bug with Istanbul itself, see https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul/issues/613

---

I am trying to use Mocha and Istanbul for code coverage in my Node v6 project, where I am using a lot of ES6 features already.

I have set up a watcher with Mocha, and my tests *are all passing*. Yet, when I try to use Istanbul to generate code coverage reports, all the default parameter values in the functions are ignored, and thus, the underlying tests are failing.

Ie.

```
id = ({param = 'none'} = {}) => {
    return param;
}
```

Makes the following test fail :

```
expect(id()).to.equal('none');
```

**I am not using Babel to transpile ES6 to ES5, I am using Node v6 and using only native Node v6 features**

Thanks !

Comment: Are you missing a `function` keyword there or is that a method?

Comment: It was within an object, but I just edited it so it's more clear now :)

Comment: Maybe try `id = (param = 'none') => param;` instead?

Comment: The point is that `param` is not set to 'none' when not passed, I can put a console.log or something else, it is just not set.

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me. Have you tried reporting it?

Comment: I think I will have to ! I just updated my question since I was wrong when I wrote the example, the problem lies with desstructured default parameter values. Thanks for your time

Comment: Please let us know if you filed a bug with istanbul, so we can subscribe to it, thanks.

Comment: My bad, just edited my post with the link.